# Is there a way to hide variables in cout (C++)?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm having an issue figuring out how to hide a specific variable (if that is even possible) in a cout function. Basically I need to do a number guess game, which would be easy enough except our teacher wants us to do it like a random math equation. Which... would honestly still be fairly easy except the way we have to do it is the program has to randomly create the problem and then randomly pick one of the 3 numbers to display and the user has to guess the other two missing numbers. For example if the program picked 20 + 32 = 52 it could potentially display __ + 32 = __.

I've gotten that far however I can't figure out how to make it so it displays like that but still allows me to put the line something like this

```
    cout << num1 //Hidden << " + " << num2 << " = " << num3 //Hidden
```

However like I said I don't even know if that is possible if not then I will probably have to rewrite the whole program. This is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, random1, guess1, guess2;
    string play = "";

    cout << "Would you like to run the number guessing program? (enter yes or no): ";
    getline(cin, play);
    for (int i = 0; i < play.length(); i++)
    {
        play[i] = tolower(play[i]);
    }

    //Random seed
    srand(time(0));

    while (play == "yes")
    {
        //Generate random numbers and num3
        num1 = 1 + rand() % 50 + 1;
        num2 = 1 + rand() % 50 + 1;
        num3 = num1 + num2;
        int pickRandom[3] = { num1, num2, num3 };

        //Display random elements
        random1 = pickRandom[rand() % 3];

        if (random1 == num1){
            cout << "\nYour randomly generated number problem: " << num1 << " + " << "__" << " = " << "__" << endl;
        }
        if (random1 == num2){
            cout << "\nYour randomly generated number problem: " << "__" << " + " << num2 << " = " << "__" << endl;
        }
        if (random1 == num3){
            cout << "\nYour randomly generated number problem: " << "__" << " + " << "__" << " = " << num3 << endl;
        }
        //Get Guesses
        cout << "\nBased off of this information please make an educated guess as to what the two missing numbers are.";
        cout << "\n\nGuess for number 1 (between 1 and 100): ";
        cin >> guess1;
        while ((guess1 > 100) || (guess1 < 0))
        {
            cout << "\nSorry you need to enter an integer between 1 and 100" << endl;
            cout << "\nGuess for number 1 (between 1 and 100): ";
            cin >> guess1;
        }
        cout << "\n\nGuess for number 2 (between 1 and 100): ";
        cin >> guess2;
        while ((guess2 > 100) || (guess2 < 0))
        {
            cout << "\nSorry you need to enter an integer between 1 and 100" << endl;
            cout << "\nGuess for number 2 (between 1 and 100: ";
            cin >> guess2;
        }
        if (guess1 == )
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're already doing this in the lines that say "Your randomly generated number problem"

Comment: As @MattMcNabb said, what's the problem with the code you currently have?

Comment: I mean I have it not displaying the variable, but I want to be able to write the line like I have in the original post so I can basically just do if(guess1 == num1) then it says "blah blah". But the way I have it now I have no way of doing that. So if the program randomly selects num3 to display and the user picks 52 as their first guess when it checks to see if it matches a number it will. But it won't be the proper number. They need to be guessing the numbers that aren't shown. Not the one that is shown.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, keep a sequence of flags for which have been guessed so far and display the data based on if the flags are set or not. The intially displayed number is just stored as a true flag here. Make this a function and output conditionally based on the flags. Get the code compiling correctly then post it over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as you are likely in a great spot to learn a lot if you do this. Ping me if you do end up posting on vode review, I'll have a look.

Comment: @HypeFree I can't figure out what you are asking; it might help if you posted a complete example of the expected output of your program (also showing user inputs)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to "hide" something printed with `cout << ...`. Just don't print it. (Print. Or print not. There is no hide.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide variables in `cout`. But you can use a variable instead of hardcoding "__".

For instance, you can simply write this:

```
  if(guessed_var1_correctly)
      var1 = num1
  else
      var1 = "__"

  if(guessed_var2_correctly)
      var2 = num2
  else
      var2 = "__"

  if(guessed_var3_correctly)
      var3 = num3
  else
      var3 = "__"

  cout << "\nYour randomly generated number problem: " << var1 << " + " << var2 << " = " << var3" << endl;
```

where var1, var2, var3 are output variables. If the player guesses it correctly, it'll display the actual value num1, num2, or num3. If not, it'll simply display "__".

Comment: Unfortunately that won't actually work for what I need it to do. They only receive two guess at a time and if either of the numbers they guess are the hidden ones then the program needs to say "One of the numbers is correct" or "Neither of the numbers are correct" and then they get to guess again. If you can't actually use some hide function I think I'm going to have to rewrite the code in some other way. I appreciate the suggestion though.